# Как правильно настроить кеширование статики

Tags: nginx, кэширование

вот есть [сервис](http://highloadtools.com/cachecontrol)  для теста кеширования страниц, у меня выдало сообщение - `This page has Cache-Control, but "Expires" header is in the past.` как правильно настроить кеш на сервере nginx. И есть ли смысл применять [cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/)

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, полностью заголовки, с которыми отдает статику ваш сервер.

Answer (score 2):

Expires – посмотрите заголовки, с которыми отдает статику ваш сервер. И перепроверьте настройки даты-времени и часового пояса на сервере.

CloudFlare – есть смысл при большом трафике. Из минусов – иногда Роскомнадзор блокирует сайт, который тоже пользуется CF – по IP – и если ваш сайт использует тот же выходной узел CF, то заблокируется и ваш невинный проект. У меня так было.